# await not waiting for async function to return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, firebase-storage

I'm using react with firebase where I need to upload some pictures to firebase storage and then save the download url that gets returned from the upload function to store that value on firestore.

This is my image uploading function

```js
const imageUpload = async (image) => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
    uploadTask.on(
      'state_changed',
      (snapshot) => {},
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        storage
          .ref('images')
          .child(image.name)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            setImageUrl(url);
            console.log(url);
            return url;
          });
      }
    );
  };
```

And this is my on submit handler

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let entry = {
      author: currentUser.email,
      body,
    };
    if (image) {
      await imageUpload(image).then(async (url) => {
        console.log(url);
        entry = {
          author: currentUser.email,
          body,
          imageUrl,
        };
        try {
          await createEntry(entry).then(() => {
            setBody('');
            setShowSnackbar(true);
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    } 

    try {
      await createEntry(entry).then(() => {
        setBody('');
        setShowSnackbar(true);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

However this doesn't work because the console shows undefined first and then the url which means that the await is not waiting for the url to be returned. How do i resolve this?

Comment: where is the `await`?

Comment: You have an `async` function that doesn't use the `await` keyword. This typically indicates a bug and, in this case, it highlights your bug.

Comment: Okay, I've rewrote the code and removed async and await. How do I wait for the function to return the url and then continue submit?

Comment: Actually, I would advise that you _promisify_ `uploadTask.on` and then `await` it. Something like `const uploadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => uploadTask.on('state_changed', () => {}, reject, resolve); await uploadPromise; return storage
          .ref('images') // etc. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing things.

You don't need to use then on your promises if you are using async / await

Using the async/await idiom your code should look more like

```js
async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let entry = {
    author: currentUser.email,
    body,
  };

  if (image) {
    const url = await imageUpload(image);
    entry = {
      author: currentUser.email,
      body,
      imageUrl,
    };
    try {
      await createEntry(entry);
      setBody("");
      setShowSnackbar(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  try {
    await createEntry(entry);
    setBody("");
    setShowSnackbar(true);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function imageUpload(image) {
  const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {},
      (error) => {
        reject(error);
      },
      () => {
        storage
          .ref("images")
          .child(image.name)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            setImageUrl(url);
            resolve(url);
          });
      }
    );
  });
}
```

`async/await` is actually intended to make programming with promises somehow 'feel' synchronous. Using then and callbacks, beside the fact that the code would not work, makes it taking no benefit from the syntax.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Concepts

Comment: I've tried that already but if I console log after 'const url = await imageUpload(image)' this line, I get undefined

Comment: @ShamimFahad I've edited the answer, the point is NOT to use then

Comment: I know what you meant, I used .then after it wasn't working this way.

Comment: @ShamimFahad the issue relies in the imageUpload function as well, I've edited the answer with a version of imageUpload that looks more like what should be used if using async/await

Answer (score 2):

The issue is primarily because of await and then are used together.
By converting your code to use await only can help.

Imagine a scenario where a `function c` is called when `function a` call to an asynchronous `function b` resolves:

```
const a = () => {
     b().then(() => c());
};
```

Here’s the same program, written using async/await instead of promise:

```
const a = async () => {
    await b();
    c();
};
```

So your logic of image upload can look like code below and you can convert rest of the code:

```
const url = await imageUpload(image)
console.log(url);
entry = {
  author: currentUser.email,
  body,
  imageUrl,
};
```

and the imageUpload function can look like,

```
async function imageUpload(image) {
  try {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    // Create the file metadata
    const metadata = {     contentType: "image/jpeg" };
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(`${this.name}/` + image.name);
    const uploadTaskSnapshot = await fileRef.put(file, metadata);
    const downloadURL = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    setImageUrl(url);
    console.log(url);
    return downloadURL;
 } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERR ===", error);
 }
}
```

Comment: The op imageUpload version does not return a promise. Using await on it will have no effect

Comment: @36ve, Ok, I just edited answer with the sample imageUpload function